# What's the correct way to inject common properties into an activerecord class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mixins

I planned on using this module (full exmpample here http://pastie.org/1098444)

```
puts "Name_and_key was referenced."

module Name_and_key

  def normalize(s)
    s.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\-x00-\x7F]/n, '').to_s
  end

  def name=(name)
    self[:name] = name
    self[:key] = normalize(name).downcase
  end

  def name
    self[:name]
  end

  def key=(key)
    self[:key] = normalize(key).downcase
  end

  def key
    self[:key]
  end

end
```

but it seems these values do not arrive at the model.

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Name_and_key

  has_many :tiles
  validates_presence_of :name, :key
end
```

and

```
cat = Category.create do |c|
 c.name = "cat"
end
```

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: categories.name may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2010-08-15 23:20:43', '2010-08-15 23:20:43', 980190962)

Is this a valid approach at all, if not how could this be done? If indeed, what is my mistake?

A failing unit test

```
test "can be created" do
cat = Category.create do |c|
  c.name = "cat"
end
tile = Tile.create do |t|
  t.name = "test"
  t.category = cat
end
assert tile.save
```

end

Some trace

```
  1) Error:
```

test_can_be_created(TileTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: categories.name may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2010-08-16 02:06:43', '2010-08-16 02:06:43', 980190962)
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `rescue in log'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:194:in`log'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:135:in `execute'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:239:in`insert_fixture'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:634:in `block in insert_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:570:in`each'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:570:in `insert_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:514:in`block (4 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:514:in `each'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:514:in`block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:512:in`block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:104:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:503:in`block in create_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb:55:in `silence'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:502:in`create_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:961:in `load_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:926:in`setup_fixtures'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in`run'

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding `validates_presence_of :name` to capture those errors on the ruby side. Your app tries to save a seemingly valid object to the DB, with name being NULL, which the ruby side allows. Now your DB blows up because you set a NOT NULL there, which doesn't like what you're saving there.

Comment: shouldn't this achieve the same?

Comment: and it really does not change anything. I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry. #read_attribute wasn't what you wanted. Seems like #[]= works too. I think your problem is that you're saving the object premature and got some NOT NULL columns on your DB. I suggest adding `validates_presence_of :name` to capture those errors on the ruby side.

Comment: category validates this.

of course the problem are null values. my question is - given the above scenario: why are they null?

Comment: aha!

ruby-1.9.2-rc2 > c = Category.new(:name =>"Test")
Name_and_key was referenced.
NoMethodError: private method `write_attribute' called for #<Category:0x000001029f3e60>
 from /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/gems/activemodel-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'

Comment: I put self[:key] = ... back in and I now can new up items in the console, but I cannot 'create' them.

Comment: See my answer. Your row (Category instance) is valid ruby-side but not DB-side. That's the only thing I can tell you by what you gave me here. And probably put the backtrace to a pastebin, it looks aweful here.

Comment: I think we're down to 'Show me a full test that fails. Least code possible plz. Incl. a DB migration that reproduces your schema.'

Comment: I should note this is ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.